# Is it possible/how can I enter data into and submit a form on a remote server using jQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have a form on a remote server, consisting of just a text box and a submit button. Once this form is submitted (PHP) XML is returned. How can I go about using ajax/jQuery to fill out this form, submit it, and receive the XML to process?

Comment: is your php on the remote server as well?

Comment: The jquery is being served from your server, not the remote server, correcT?

Comment: AJAX just sends and receives HTTP requests/responses, so yes, theoretically it's possible. However, knowing if it's possible in your case relies on a ton of information you haven't given to us. First, you'll need a browser that doesn't block cross-domain AJAX.

Comment: check the url and the data required for the POST action and simply do the same request directly to the url with those POST data!

Comment: Or, load jquery into node.js and make it from there, however, at that point you might aswell just use node.js to make the request, or whatever server-side language you're already using.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear, the AJAX/jQuery will be on a PhoneGap app, so essentially a different domain.

Comment: Then technically yes you can do it, as long as  you control the domain with the form, or it already has CORS headers enabled for that page and the action page.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, I think you should be heading somewhere in the direction of the following JS. Ofcourse, this is light thinking, there could be all kind of implications with the following  (eg. XSS protection etc..). But if we're talking a simple, plain form, I think this could work.

Also, expanding the following with some failure fallbacks etc would be good practice. For documentation on the Ajax function, check [the API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
// This should be the URL where your <form> action's value is pointing at
var url = 'http://remote/form/action';

// The textfield's data you want to submit
var textFieldValue = 'foobar'; 

$.ajax(
    url,
    {
        'type': 'POST',                        // Could also be GET, depending on your form
        'data': {
            'textFieldName': textFieldValue,   
        },
        'success': function (data) {
            console.log(data);                 // Your raw XML in a string
        }
    }
);
```

**Edit**: As Kevin B mentioned, you'll be heading into cross-domain policy problems with the above, making this situation that more complex. Therefor you should need to make sure you have CORS arranged on the targeted domain. [See Wikipedia CORS for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

Comment: The success will not get executed due to the same-origin policy, therefore the xml will not be accessible.

Comment: @KevinB You're totally right, thanks. I've added CORS information to my original post.